# Do you use an apostrophe with opinions?

Tags: punctuation, apostrophe

Are the following sentences correct?

> 1. **John's** opinion about the sports car shocked his friend.
> 2. The Board of **Director's** opinion about the unresolved issue is that it should have already been dealt with long time ago.

Comment: In a word, yes.   You might want to say "The opinion of the Board of Directors about...", though; it would be a little clearer.

Comment: In the second sentence the apostrope goes after the s, not before.  The noun is Board of Directors, not Board of Director.

Answer (score 2):

An apostrophe declares the origin and ownership of the particular object following that subject, correct? An opinion, while abstract in the physical sense, is still an object/noun, so in your examples, John has an opinion that is his. The apostrophe is correct in claiming John's opinion as his.